# Pointer initialization. How does it work?

Tags: c, dev-c++

I finished my programming classes in C, and thought I would write some code down. BOOM! I run into so many problems. I guess the C language is so complicated, even a book can't explain how it works entirely.

This is my problem(I am trying to display something using a pointer)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
   char *a;
   system("cls");
   *a = {"hello"};
   printf("%s",a);
   getch();
}
```

Comment: Actually, heaps of books explain pointers very well.  Which books have you read that were not sufficient?

Comment: @paddy i guess Niit's book does not explain it

Comment: K&R is a very short book that explains the C language in its entirety.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves K&R is a good book but, since it hasn't been revised since 1988, there are significant parts of the current C language which it does not cover.

Comment: @NigelHarper totally agreed, but it's a good introduction for a beginner nevertheless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just providing another insight for you..
just now I tried this in Dev-C++ 5.6.3 and it works..

if you assign the value directly when you are declaring it, it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    char *a = {"hello"};
    printf("%s",a);
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

and one more thing, `clrscr` is not a standard c function (it didn't work in my test), so how about using `cls` in `stdlib` like I did.. hope it's useful..

Answer (score 1):

```
*a = {"hello"};
```

This dereferenced the pointer and assigned something to that memory location.  The reason it crashed is because the pointer was uninitialised, *ie* it did not point at anything (actually it did point at something, but that something was an undefined memory location).

If you had done the following, your program would have worked:

```
a = "hello";
```

The type of `a` is `char*`.  The type of `"hello"` is also `char*`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you show me the whole working code. I would be pleased

Answer (score 1):

You don't give value to a pointer to char this way:

```
*a = {"hello"};
```

You have to use:

```
a="hello";
```

I don't understand very well what you are trying to do. If you only want to print "hello" in your screen, why do you use a pointer to char? What is the getch() for? You use that function this way: http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch Do you intend to read a character?

I would only do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

What are you exactly trying to do?

This is a good reference guide: http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    char *a;// a  is pointer which address is store in stack and when u initialize with any string then string is store in code section which cant be change
    clrscr();
    a = "hello";// this is the way to store the string but if when u assign while declaring as char *a= hello this will accept Remember hello is store in code where as address of pointer a is store in stack section   

    printf("%s", a);
    getch();
}
```

~